# How can I use a coalesce operator in a DRY way; when assigned value is null, keep own value

Tags: c#, .net, null-coalescing

I am sending value in object `orderContract` which will replace values of entity if contract value is not null but if contract property is null it will retain its own value.

Currently I have used coalesce operator as in 2nd line of code. Is there a way where I don't have to repeat existing value?

```
 var ordersEntity = _repository.Read<Entities.Orders>(orderContract.Id);

ordersEntity.Status = orderContract.Status ?? ordersEntity.Status;
```

Comment: No, there is no `??=` or `?=` operator.

Comment: No. The only alternative is to use an `if` to only assign if its null, but you're still repeating the code.   `if (orderContract.Status == null) { orderContract.Status = ordersEntity.Status; }`

Comment: You could change the property to be nullable, and change the property's setter to ignore nulls, but that seems silly to save yourself a few key presses (Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V on Windows)... Not to mention it would add code to those places where you get the value (to add `.GetValueOrDefault()` or `?.Value` or whatever).

Comment: There actually [might be a `??=`](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2072) eventually (with different semantics than what you need here!), but even then I'd still prefer an explicit `if (orderContract.Status != null) ordersEntity.Status = orderContract.Status` over a redundant assignment, which might have side effects if you're unlucky. (The fact that a previous comment got the logic wrong is also an argument in favor of that, I think.)

Comment: If that something you repeat to much you can move it in the setter/getter

Comment: @RenéVogt The `??=` is proposed for C# 8, but it would still not apply if you read carefully... Also @Amy: your assignment is not the same as OP's.

Comment: @PeterB ah right, msiread that.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I will go with use of Coalesce rather than if statement.